# Iframe doesn't reload if only query param is changed

Tags: angular, iframe

I have an Iframe which loads game streams. but it does not reload when only query params are changed

I tried with 2 regular links on this code like google.com and google.com/maps for example and they reload just fine

```
public iframeBaseSrc = 'https://mystreamsite.com?gameId=';
public iframeUrl = '';
public changeSrc(number) {
 this.iframeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl (iframeBaseSrc + number);
}
```

html

```
<iframe [src]="iframeUrl"  width="700" height="500"></iframe>
<div (click)=changeSrc(123)>stream 1</div>
<div (click)=changeSrc(345)>stream 2</div>
```

The iframe just gets stuck on the first url , when I inspect it, url changes but the stream stays the same. any ideas why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mr.void I've read that link and can't see how my question doesn't meet the requirements

Comment: I cant reproduce your issue, its working fine in my test-case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zustt